# Knockout data-bind css if function

Tags: html, class, knockout.js, data-binding, element

I want to add a class to an element if the title of the page includes "Home".
Currently, I use this:

```
<li data-bind="css: { 'active': function(){return document.title.indexOf('Home') > -1;}}">
```

However this does not work, this function does not get executed...
How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knockout wraps the value in a computed function in a way that resembles this:

```
Input: "yourClassName": whateverYouPutIn
Output: "yourClassName": ko.computed(function() { return whateverYouPutIn; })
```

In your case, you put in a function, which will result in a "truethy" value setting the `active` class. You can fix this by:

#### Option 1 (quick): Don't wrap it in a function

```
<li data-bind="css: { 
    'active': document.title.indexOf('Home') > -1
  }"></li>
```

#### Option 2 (not recommended): Fix the typo (`funciton`) and call the function

```
<li data-bind="css: { 
    'active': (function() {
      return document.title.indexOf('Home') > -1;
     }())
  }"></li>
```

#### Option 3: Add these kinds of properties to your viewmodel

```
var vm = {
  // set when VM is initialized
  isActive: document.title.indexOf("Home"), 
  // if you want to check the title during data-binding
  isActiveDuringBind: function() {
    return document.title.indexOf("Home");
  }
}
```

With either

```
<li data-bind="css: {'active': isActive }"></li>
```

or

```
<li data-bind="css: {'active': isActiveDuringBind() }"></li>
```

Note that using the DOM api outside of custom bindings is considered "bad practice"... But in this case I guess you can get away with it...

Note that because there are no observable values being used, your class will not toggle when you change `document.title`.

Comment: Thank you for the extended answer, made it work! Sorry for the stupid typo though.